# Oracle 12c - example of local partitioned index

Tags: oracle, indexing, partition

I have a table in Oracle with 300M records. It is partitioned by varchar column and sub-partitioned by another varchar column. e.g.

table t1 has columns (a,b,c,d,e) and it is partitioned on column 'c' and sub-partitioned on column 'd'.

How to create local partitioned index on these 2 columns?

Is it just:
`create index c_idx on t1 (c) local;` 
`create index d_idx on t1 (d) local;`

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is right. Did you try? Was the result not as expected?

Comment: I did but want to make sure did not miss anything.. There is no specific key-word for index to become 'partitioned'? It is all about using partition column or not, correct?

Comment: The keyword is `local` which you have in there. Or, as the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/VLDBG/index-partitioning.htm#VLDBG1251) says: _A local index is created by specifying the LOCAL attribute. Oracle constructs the local index so that it is equipartitioned with the underlying table. Oracle partitions the index on the same columns as the underlying table, creates the same number of partitions or subpartitions, and gives them the same partition bounds as corresponding partitions of the underlying table._